# WPF Data Binding ComboBox in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a DataGrid and I want to populate a column that contains a ComboBox with a dynamic ItemsSource of elements, based on the row. I have the combo box display correctly, and the correct list of elements are populated in the list, as pulled in from the `AvailableLogFileProcessTypes` property, which is a ReadOnlyCollection. However, when the selection is made by the user in the combobox, the `LogFileProcessType` property is not set to the selection.

**Data:**

```
Property LogFileDirectories, IEnumerable<LogFileData>,
LogFileData:
public LogFileProcessType LogFileProcessType{get;set;}
public ReadOnlyCollection<LogFileProcessType> AvailableLogFileProcessTypes { get; set; }
```

The property currently has a backing field, and the breakpoint in the set property does not get hit, so I know it is localized to the binding setup. What is wrong with my XAML that is preventing the property from being set?

As you can see, I've tried setting both the SelectedValue and SelectedItem in the CellEditingTemplate and the CellTemplate. I am not sure which of these is appropriate.

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LogFileDirectories, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="0,0,0,35" Grid.RowSpan="3">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Processed" Binding="{Binding Path=IsProcessingComplete, Mode=OneWay}" Width="70" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="template">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableLogFileProcessTypes}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>      
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableLogFileProcessTypes}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                            
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>                        
</DataGrid.Columns>                    
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Damascus response for thought process.

Need to Specify UpdateSourceTrigger on CellTemplate / CelLEditTemplate. This triggers the property change.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="template">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableLogFileProcessTypes}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>      
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableLogFileProcessTypes}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                            
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this to your `ComboBox` :

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=LogFileProcessType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableLogFileProcessTypes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Therefore, with an `UpdateSourceTrigger` set to `PropertyChanged`, each time the object `AvailableLogFileProcessTypes` will change and call `OnPropertyChanged`, the `ItemsSource` will be refreshed.

Comment: My issue is that when the combo box selection is changed by the user, LogFileProcessType isn't changed in the backing data object. I am fine on AvailableLogFileProcessTypes. This list doesn't change when LogFileProcessType changes.

Comment: My bad, I didn't understand correctly. Could you add a bit of detail on how your objects are organized? Where exactly is `LogFileProcessType` in your hierarchy?

Comment: I added the data section. I am giving you a +1 since you got me on the right track. See edit.